Can a British judge convict and sentence someone for contempt in their own court on the spot?
There are many videos of US judges imposing punishments on people who commit obvious contempt of court in their own courts in front of them. They can order the person taken to jail on the spot.
Do British judges have the same power for people who are openly contempuous in front of them?


Can a British judge convict and sentence someone for contempt in their
own court on the spot?

Yes.
This practice, called "direct criminal contempt", which is a legacy of the days when lords personally presided over resolving disputes between their subjects in their own courtyards in the feudal era before professional judges were delegated with the authority to fill that role, originates in the courts of England and Wales and remains in place there (the statute itself does not comprehensively spell out the process for direct contempt in all U.K. courts):

In England and Wales (a common law jurisdiction), the law on contempt
is partly set out in case law (common law), and partly codified by the
Contempt of Court Act 1981. Contempt may be classified as
criminal or civil. The maximum penalty for criminal contempt under the
1981 Act is committal to prison for two years.
Disorderly, contemptuous or insolent behaviour toward the judge or
magistrates while holding the court, tending to interrupt the due
course of a trial or other judicial proceeding, may be prosecuted as
"direct" contempt. The term "direct" means that the court itself cites
the person in contempt by describing the behaviour observed on the
record. Direct contempt is distinctly different from indirect
contempt, wherein another individual may file papers alleging contempt
against a person who has willfully violated a lawful court order.
There are limits to the powers of contempt created by rulings of
European Court of Human Rights. Reporting on contempt of court, the
Law Commission commented that "punishment of an advocate for what he
or she says in court, whether a criticism of the judge or a
prosecutor, amounts to an interference with his or her rights under
article 10 of the ECHR" and that such limits must be "prescribed by
law" and be "necessary in a democratic society", citing Nikula v
Finland.
Criminal contempt
The Crown Court is a superior court according to the Senior Courts Act
1981, and Crown Courts have the power to punish contempt. The
Divisional Court as part of the High Court has ruled that this power
can apply in these three circumstances:

Contempt "in the face of the court" (not to be taken literally; the judge does not need to see it, provided it took place within the court
precincts or relates to a case currently before that court);

Disobedience of a court order; and

Breaches of undertakings to the court.


Where it is necessary to act quickly, a judge may act to impose
committal (to prison) for contempt.
Where it is not necessary to be so urgent, or where indirect contempt
has taken place the Attorney General can intervene and the Crown
Prosecution Service will institute criminal proceedings on his behalf
before a Divisional Court of the King's Bench Division of the High
Court of Justice of England and Wales. In January 2012, for example, a
juror who had researched information on the internet was jailed for
contempt of court. Theodora Dallas, initially searching for the
meaning of the term "grievous bodily harm", added search criteria
which localised her search and brought to light another charge against
the defendant. Because she then shared this information with the other
jurors, the judge stated that she had compromised the defendant's
right to a fair trial and the prosecution was abandoned.
Magistrates' courts also have powers under the 1981 Act to order to
detain any person who "insults the court" or otherwise disrupts its
proceedings until the end of the sitting. Upon contempt being admitted
or proved the (invariably) District Judge (sitting as a magistrate)
may order committal to prison for a maximum of one month, impose a
fine of up to £2,500, or both.
It will be contempt to bring an audio recording device or
picture-taking device of any sort into an English court without the
consent of the court.
It will not be contempt according to section 10 of the Act for a
journalist to refuse to disclose his sources, unless the court has
considered the evidence available and determined that the information
is "necessary in the interests of justice or national security or for
the prevention of disorder or crime".

Historically, this power was not shared by judges in courts in civil law countries, although Belgium is an exception, and has provided this authority on a statutory basis to its judges.

I guess it would then be a separate question to ask what happens to people acting disruptive in court in other law systems. I presume there must be some action the judge can take.

Here's a good link summing it up: https://www.gov.uk/contempt-of-court

@PMF The law of other common law jurisdictions and Belgium is summarized at the first link in this answer, some common law jurisdictions have limited the historical authority of judges to impose direct criminal contempt sanctions. Historically, in civil law jurisdictions other than Belgium, disturbing the peace in court was treated the same way it was when someone disturbed the peace in other places, i.e. with police arresting someone with further criminal proceedings in a separate court case.

Since the OP said "British" I feel that I should point out that Scottish law is similar, but completely distinct.
